# Irreducible polynomial in AES and GNU Octave

Tags: aes, octave, rijndael, finite-field

In the [Rijndael AES proposal](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf) in section 2.1.2 they have chosen m(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 and said it is an irreducible polynomial. This polynomial corresponds to integer 283.

Further in section 4.2.3, they have defined the value of M, the matrix used in `MixColumn` operation. I was trying to find its multiplicative inverse M⁻¹ in octave. I used the command

```
y = gf(M, 8, 283)
```

And octave gave me the following error:

> error: `gf`: primitive polynomial (283) of Galois Field must be irreducible

Can anyone please help me in explaining why I am getting this error? I have very little knowledge of fields, groups and similar abstract concepts.

Comment: Have you checked if `y = primpoly (8)`well returns the irreducible polynomial used in AES?

Comment: `primpoly(8)` returns $D^8+D^4+D^3+D^2+1$ i.e . 285

Comment: This polynomial is also an irreducible one over $GF(2^8)$ but try `y = primpoly(8, all)`to get all the irreducible polynomials and then check if the one used in AES appears.

Comment: Tried that as well. It doesn't.

Comment: Really? So I think there might be an error in their implementation... You can try to contact the support or developpers team.

Comment: I suspect that the Octave implementation insists that the value 2 in the generated field is primitive (that is, $2^x$ takes on all possible nonzero values in the field) as well.  If they insist on that, well, that's an error; that's not a requirement for a field (there must be primitive elements, but 2 needn't be one of them)

Comment: @Siddhant 0x11D is indeed the first *primitive* polynomial, but 0x11B is the first irreducible

Comment: I was also able to replicate the problem, it complains about 283 but not 285

Comment: @RichieFrame Octave complains that its irreducible. I think it should complain that its not primitive. I tried the same thing in matlab. It warns that 283 is not primitive. There must me some problem in octave's implementation

Comment: @Siddhant Then a [bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave) would useful.

Comment: The error message is wrong in stating that 0x11b is not irreducible. Every non-zero number for the 0x11b field is a power of 3. There are 30 irreducible 9 bit polynomials which can be used for GF(2^8), but only 16 of these have 2 as a primitive element.